# How should my nail protection plates be improved to pass inspection?

Tags: plumbing, framing

I failed a rough inspection and could use some help. What's wrong with these nail plates?

I know the holes need to be bigger and PEX suspenders added now, but should the nail plates be bigger?

The inspector wasn't of any help. Does this need a bigger nail plate?

[image: What's wrong with these nail plates?]

[image: Does this need a bigger strikeplate?]

[image: Additional photos]
[image: Additional photos]
[image: Additional photos]

Comment: What, *exactly*, was written on the inspection failure notice?

Comment: I second @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact.  An inspector should mention what are the fail points, not just mark as fail and do better next time.  Can also check for your local plumbing code, what is good here might be bad there.

Comment: I don't think it is the strike plates.   In fact I have never put strike plates for PVC...   pex sometimes.      It looks like you don't have a trap but I can't see everything.

Comment: The inspector may not have been willing to help you plan to fix this work, but I can guarantee they told you what you failed on. Share that information with us.

Comment: No written notice. All it says online is Rough failed not to code. Pex holes need to be bigger to allow for expansion and contraction, plus suspension clamps. I was told the 90s are illegal, hence why I asked if the long sweep would be the correct ones. He mentioned that all the strike plates were incorrect, but would not say anything else.

Comment: Then you need to talk to them. Code is simply way too big for "failed not to code" to mean anything by itself.

Comment: State is RI so IPC 2018, two more pics added.

Comment: Is it possible their online system provides pass/fail but if you ask, or perhaps eventually even if you don't ask, you'll receive something more detailed?

Comment: I see issues where some of your pvc is on holes that took out way too much of the wood - especially at the top of the last picture. There are ways to compensate but a nail plate is for protection of the pipes and doesn't provide strength for the wood.

Comment: Yeah, the drain pipe holes appear to violate "Boring. The diameter of bored holes in studs shall not exceed 60 percent of the stud depth, the edge of the hole shall not be less than 5/8 inch (16 mm) from the edge of the stud, and the hole shall not be located in the same section as a cut or notch. Where the diameter of a bored hole in a stud located in exterior walls or bearing partitions is over 40 percent, such stud shall be doubled and not more than two successive doubled studs shall be so bored."

Comment: Given the pair of 90's are on what appears to be a dry vent, not sure the inspector is correct about that. But there isn't a compelling reason for the second one not to be a 45 located closer to the drain pipe, and I do wonder where the cleanout is.

Comment: Are you missing the cinch rings on the long blue pipe in the bottom picture at the elbow? I can't quite tell from the picture

Comment: If this hasn't been mentioned already, if the plumbing failed because of the nail plates, among other things, and the plumbers installed all of it, then they need to fix the problem. They can make the calls to the inspector to get the details

Comment: @Jack I assumed OP is "the plumbers" in this case :)

Comment: What is *"rough"*? Not *"[rough-in](https://www.fieldwire.com/resources/construction-glossary/rough-in/)"*? There is also [a corresponding tag](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rough-in), but [its tag wiki](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/rough-in/info) is empty.

Comment: @Armand, I assumed one was hired, but to read it again, there is no reason to think they did.

Answer (score 6):

**Regarding nailing plates and boring holes**

2019 RI plumbing code (is that what your jurisdiction is using?):

First part of "Structural Safety" Appendix:

> Appendix C Structural Safety
>
> This appendix may only be utilized when specifically permitted by a local or regional sewer authority having
> jurisdiction, or the Rhode Island Department of Environmental Management for individual sewage disposal systems.
>
> Section C101 Cutting, Notching and Boring in Wood Members
>
> [BS] C101.1 Joist Notching
> Notches on the ends of joists shall not exceed one-fourth the joist depth. Holes bored in joists shall not be within 2 inches (51 mm) of the top or bottom of the joist, and the diameter of any such hole shall not exceed one-third the depth of the joist. Notches in the top or bottom of joists shall not exceed one-sixth the depth and shall not be located in the middle third of the span.
>
> [BS] C101.2 Stud Cutting and Notching
> In exterior walls and bearing partitions, any wood stud is permitted to be cut or notched to a depth not exceeding 25 percent of its width. Cutting or notching of studs to a depth not greater than 40 percent of the width of the stud is permitted in nonbearing partitions supporting no loads other than the weight of the partition.
>
> [BS] C101.3 Bored Holes
> The diameter of bored holes in wood studs shall not exceed 40 percent of the stud depth. The diameter of bored holes in wood studs shall not exceed 60 percent of the stud depth in nonbearing partitions. The diameter of bored holes in wood studs shall not exceed 60 percent of the stud depth in any wall where each stud is doubled, provided that not more than two such successive doubled studs are so bored. The edge of the bored hole shall not be closer than 5/8 inch (15.9 mm) to the edge of the stud. Bored holes shall be not located at the same section of stud as a cut or notch.

Below section gives specifics about size and thickness of nailing plates; are yours thick enough? Aside from the too-big holes through wood issue that @Ecnerwal mentioned, your plates do not seem to cover the minimum additional coverage above sole plates and below top plates.

> 305.6 Protection Against Physical Damage
> In concealed locations where piping, other than cast-iron or galvanized steel, is installed through holes or notches in studs, joists, rafters or similar members less than 11/2 inches (38 mm) from the nearest edge of the member, the pipe shall be protected by steel shield plates. Such shield plates shall have a thickness of not less than 0.0575 inch (1.463 mm) (No. 16 gage). Such plates shall cover the area of the pipe where the member is notched or bored, and shall extend not less than 2 inches (51 mm) above sole plates and below top plates

Why not take lots of photos from all angles and pay for an hour or two of a local plumber's time to have him/her look at the photos and point out what needs to be fixed. If the wood holes issue requires wholesale rerouting of pipes outside of the wall cavities, it's better to learn that soon.

Here are the [Table of Contents/Appendices of RI 2019 plumbing code](https://shop.iccsafe.org/media/wysiwyg/material/5920S19-TOC.pdf) and [Interactive 2019 RI Plumbing Code sections](https://up.codes/viewer/rhode_island/ri-plumbing-code-2019).